# Can Code Style preferences be shared?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I've read that VS2017 supports .editorConfig and that you can create your own .editorConfig files at solution/project level and share them, however, I am wondering if the machine/user -wide configuration can somehow be shared?

I mean these settings:

[image]

Or am I completely wrong in thinking that these settings are related to the new .editorConfig support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You should go:

1. Open a solution in Visual Studio.
2. Go to "Tools"
3. Go to "Import and Export Settings"
4. Choose Export
5. Follow prompts.

If you follow the export, you'll see that it exports those configuration settings into the script to parse and read when imported into another instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I thought there would be some new form instead of the common one. Thanks!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto They did introduce some extensions you can build with Roslyn, to enforce them.  But if you don't go that route, the common way still works.

Comment: Where could I look for them?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Those extensions to enforce?

Comment: Yes, those. At my company we have many juniors and we're looking to force some standards we have

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto We use this at my company, which is built into ReShaper. https://github.com/StyleCop

Comment: Thought StyleCop was dead, had no idea they had rebuilt it for Roslyn. Thanks!